# "Out of Paper" message when it isn't out of paper

Tags: brother-printer

My Brother MFC-J87ODW says it is out of paper, but there is paper in the tray. I've tried unloading and reloading the paper and turning the printer off, then on again.

Comment: There's a good chance that something might be jammed between the rollers which is stopping it from loading the paper. Can you get a closer look?

Comment: http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj870dw_us_eu_as&ftype3=1964&faqid=faq00002490_023

Comment: I got this message when I stacked a few millimeters too much paper in the tray. Removing some sheets cleared the error.

Comment: For my printer, a $5 part fixed it: Brother Feeder Cam Lever (part LY2579001). See [Brother MFC-7860DW No Paper](https://superuser.com/questions/1562013/brother-mfc-7860dw-no-paper/1562014#1562014) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Follow:

1. Press Windows logo on keyboard + X Key.

   2.window opens up .From that list Select Device manager.

   3.find option printer in device manager window .

   4.click on left arrow.Then it will display printer in use

   5. Right click that printer

   6.Click on Update driver software.
   or try 
   Cleaning  the paper feed rollers in the cartridge access area. It might resolve your issue

Comment: From the description, the problem is likely inside the printer, itself, not the driver software.

Answer (score 0):

My 2305 quit loading paper and would only print using manual feed.  I did a factory reset and the problem was solved.  My printer now prints from the tray.
I did this using the buttons on top of the printer.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it means the printer is heading for end of life.

If you enjoy pain, put 1 sheet in at a time, and **maybe** it will see it.

You might be able to revive it, by cleaning replacing the rollers and probably a new paper sensor module.

Asking how much repairs are is free?  Start there.  Your better off buying a new one as repair costs will exceed sanity.  The effort of DIY is not worth it.

I have had FAR too many inkjet printers fail this way on me.  I even bought and expensive one thinking the ones I had purchased were just too cheap and poorly made.  NOPE My $300+ inkjet failed in the same manor.

Now its only laser printers for me.  Even colors ones aren't that bad when you consider the total cost of the inkjets you have already thrown away.

I had my first laser lasted over 10 years, and I only upgraded because the new models are better in every way.  Memory,speed, options, smaller, lighter, and etc.

http://theoatmeal.com/comics/printers

Answer (score 0):

Try photocopying or printing from another device if it works then I suggest restarting your computer as it is a connection problem not a printer problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Diagnostic suggestions are more appropriate as a comment, which requires a little more rep.  Answers are intended for definitive solutions, which are difficult in this case given the limited information in the question.